# Why do my components disappear when added to a panel?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, fieldset

So I have one jFrame object ,which in turn has 3 JPanels attached to it.
These JPanels are placed on NORTH,CENTER,SOUTH.
I added some buttons and labels to CENTER and SOUTH.

I added in some fieldsets on NORTH and CENTER to give it a nicer look.
Now when I try to run the program ,it doesn't show anything. My buttons and labels disappear and my fieldsets are nowhere to be found.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for you time.

```
public General() {
    super("OmniTool");
    initComponents();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(300,100);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(900, 700);

    //radiobuttons ivm dependencies
    ButtonGroup dependenciesInfo = new ButtonGroup();
    dependenciesInfo.add(rdbYesDependencies);
    dependenciesInfo.add(rdbNoDependencies);
    //boolean om te controleren of alle textareas al ingevuld zijn 
    generalInfoComplete = false;

    //creating 3 panels and add them on the same frame + giving them their location 
    JPanel oudeMod = new JPanel();
    JPanel nieuweMod = new JPanel();
    JPanel generate = new JPanel();
    this.add(oudeMod,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(nieuweMod,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(generate,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    oudeMod.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Use exisiting modfolder"));
    nieuweMod.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Create new modfolder"));

    //adding buttons and textfields to proper panels

    nieuweMod.add(jLabel2);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel3);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel4);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel5);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel7);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel8);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel9);
    nieuweMod.add(jLabel10);
    nieuweMod.add(btnBrowseMain);
    nieuweMod.add(btnBrowseMods);
    nieuweMod.add(btnDependencies);
    nieuweMod.add(rdbNoDependencies);
    nieuweMod.add(rdbYesDependencies);
    nieuweMod.add(txtDependencies);
    nieuweMod.add(txtMainDir);
    nieuweMod.add(txtModName);
    nieuweMod.add(txtModsDir);
    generate.add(btnGenerate);
}
```

EDIT1: These jFrames are on 1 jtabbedPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if "this" is the JFrame, this.add(...) won't work. You should add your components to the contentPane of the JFrame.

Comment: You mean this.getContentPane().add(...) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: No ,didnt work. I forgot to mention that there is a tabbedPane on top of the JFrame. I tried this.jTabbedPane1.add(...) ,and I only ended up with a new tab instead of the JFrame being added to the current tab.

Comment: You cannot add JFrames to a JTabbedPane, as JFrames are top level containers. Add your tabbed pane to the contentPane of the JFrame, then create a JPanel with a BorderLayout, add everything on there (the many panels in your code example) and then add that panel to your tabbed pane.

Answer (score 0):

> "So I have one jFrame object ,which in turn has 3 JPanels attached to it. These JPanels are placed on NORTH,CENTER,SOUTH. I added some buttons and labels to CENTER and SOUTH."

Each `BorderLayout` position can only hold one component. If you add a `JPanel` to the `CENTER` then add the `JButton` to the `CENTER` only the last component added (the `JButton`) will appear.

Add whatever components you need to a max 5 `JPanel`s and position those `JPanel` at the different `BorderLayout` positions.  Or you can use a different layout. Or you can use a main `JPanel` container and just add the `JPanel` to the frame. You have many options.

---

Also do all your `JFrame` housekeeping *after* you add all your components. Put them at the end of your constructor.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocation(300,100);
setVisible(true);
setResizable(true);
setSize(900, 700);
```

Don't set size either. Just `pack()`. And `setVisible()` should be the last thing you do.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setResizable(true);
setVisible(true);
```